# Google Drive API - Not listing specific shared drive

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm giving a try to the Google Drive API V3.

Having some shared drive folders access, and being administrator of all that resources, I'd like to fetch an specific one filtered by my query `q: name='Test'`.

For any reason, when I try to insert the query as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-shareddrives?authuser=1) suggest, it responses with an error that isn't pretty descriptive and doesn't help at debugging:

[image]

As well, if I execute the query without conditions, I get success with the response and it shows me the whole shared drives:

[image]

Any help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: where exactly are you testing this?   it works here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?q=name+%253D+'test'&_h=11&  Looks like theres something wrong with your javascript code.  maybe escape the 's?

Comment: I was trying here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list

Comment: What I was trying is to get the right `shared drive` folder, and query opperations to `drives.list` specifying `driveId`, `includeTeamDriveItems`, `supportsAllDrives`...

Comment: how about trying   'name' '=' 'Telco'

Comment: it throws an error ```{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}```

Comment: Sorry i cant help much i dont have access to any other drives so i cant test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198318/discussion-between-devstarlight-and-daimto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very obvious in the documentation, but as per the list of [search parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#drive_properties), all except `hidden` require that you set `useDomainAdminAccess=true` (and that the authorized user is a domain admin). You are getting this error because you are trying to search by name but not enabling domain admin mode.

Comment: This is such a good point to take in consideration and that was my mistake! Thanks!

Comment: After get a succesfull query in the google api area, I've tried to execute the same in `NodeJS` and I was receiving the same `invalid value` error. After investigating, I got confused by this documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives. It seems they are using the library the wrong way... According to the `ts` `googleapis` package code, they always expect to receive `params` object, which contains the `q` but in the example they it's different